# Pass IList<Model> From View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

#### Edit 14:19 UTC Wednesday, May 10, 2017

The generated HTML has been added to the bottom of the post, as requested. I also updated the View with my changes.

I am trying to create a view allowing users to sort (change the indices of) models in my database. The sorting is done via drag-and-drop in JavaScript, with the `Index` of the models being updated as appropriate. My problem is that when the form is posted, the `IList` of my model is empty.

#### Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Slide
    {
        public static int CurrentIndex = 0;

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public int Index
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Section
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Content
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Image")]
        public byte[] ImageData
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Image Description")]
        public string ImageDescription
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedImage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class SlideDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Slide> Slides
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

#### View

```
@model IList<WebApplication2.Models.Slide>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Reorder</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table grid" id="sort">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Index)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Section)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Content)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().ImageData);
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().ImageDescription)
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Index, new
                    {
                        htmlAttributes = new
                        {
                            name = $"slides[{i}].Index",
                            @readonly = true
                        }
                    })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Section)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Section)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Title)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Content)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Content)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].ImageData)
                    <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new
                              {
                                  id = Model[i].Id
                              })" alt="@Model[i].ImageDescription"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].ImageDescription)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].ImageDescription)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-default" name="slides"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#sort tbody').sortable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $("#sort tbody tr").each(function(index, element) {
                    var hiddenInput = $(element).children(".index").children().first();
                    hiddenInput.val(index);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Controller (Relevant Portion)

```
public ActionResult Reorder()
{
    return View(_database.Slides.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reorder(IList<Slide> slides)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(slides.Count);
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.Count; i++)
    {
        var slide = _database.Slides.Find(slides[i].Id);

        if (slide == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound($"Slide with Id {slides[i].Id} not found.");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(slide.Title);
        slide.Index = i;
    }

    _database.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The debug line is where I am checking the number of items in the `IList`, which is 0 regardless of how many items there are in the database (and therefore are passed into the view.

The view looks like this when loaded:
[image]
And then like this after I reorder:
[image]
But the changes are not getting posted properly when I hit the "Save" button.

I read elsewhere that issues with lists were commonly caused by not using consecutive indexing for the list items, but I use a loop with indexer so that shouldn't be the issue. Additionally, I have all model properties present, so the form should be able to post proper `Slide` objects.

#### Generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Reorder</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="/Slide/Reorder" method="post">    <table class="table grid" id="sort">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Index
            </th>
            <th>
                Section
            </th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Content
            </th>
            <th>
                Image;
            </th>
            <th>
                Image Description
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Index must be a number." data-val-required="The Index field is required." name="[0].Index" readonly="True" type="number" value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[0].Section" type="hidden" value="Colors" />
                    Colors
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[0].Title" type="hidden" value="Red" />
                    Red
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[0].Content" type="hidden" value="This is the color red." />
                    This is the color red.
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[0].ImageData" type="hidden" value="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" />
                    <img src="/Slide/RenderImage/1" alt="Red"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[0].ImageDescription" type="hidden" value="Red" />
                    Red
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[1].Id" type="hidden" value="2" />
                    2
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Index must be a number." data-val-required="The Index field is required." name="[1].Index" readonly="True" type="number" value="1" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[1].Section" type="hidden" value="Colors" />
                    Colors
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[1].Title" type="hidden" value="Green" />
                    Green
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[1].Content" type="hidden" value="This is the color green." />
                    This is the color green.
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[1].ImageData" type="hidden" value="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" />
                    <img src="/Slide/RenderImage/2" alt="Green"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[1].ImageDescription" type="hidden" value="Green" />
                    Green
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[2].Id" type="hidden" value="3" />
                    3
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Index must be a number." data-val-required="The Index field is required." name="[2].Index" readonly="True" type="number" value="2" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[2].Section" type="hidden" value="Colors" />
                    Colors
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[2].Title" type="hidden" value="Orange" />
                    Orange
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[2].Content" type="hidden" value="This is the color orange." />
                    This is the color orange.
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[2].ImageData" type="hidden" value="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" />
                    <img src="/Slide/RenderImage/3" alt="Orange"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[2].ImageDescription" type="hidden" value="Orange" />
                    Orange
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[3].Id" type="hidden" value="5" />
                    5
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Index must be a number." data-val-required="The Index field is required." name="[3].Index" readonly="True" type="number" value="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[3].Section" type="hidden" value="Colors" />
                    Colors
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[3].Title" type="hidden" value="Blue" />
                    Blue
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[3].Content" type="hidden" value="This is the color blue." />
                    This is the color blue.
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[3].ImageData" type="hidden" value="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" />
                    <img src="/Slide/RenderImage/5" alt="Blue"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[3].ImageDescription" type="hidden" value="Blue" />
                    Blue
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." name="[4].Id" type="hidden" value="6" />
                    6
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Index must be a number." data-val-required="The Index field is required." name="[4].Index" readonly="True" type="number" value="5" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[4].Section" type="hidden" value="Colors" />
                    Colors
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[4].Title" type="hidden" value="Yellow" />
                    Yellow
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[4].Content" type="hidden" value="This is the color yellow" />
                    This is the color yellow
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[4].ImageData" type="hidden" value="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCABkAGQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9aKKKK/wTP2gKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA//9k=" />
                    <img src="/Slide/RenderImage/6" alt="Yellow"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="[4].ImageDescription" type="hidden" value="Yellow" />
                    Yellow
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-default" name="slides"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#sort tbody').sortable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $("#sort tbody tr").each(function(index, element) {
                    var hiddenInput = $(element).children(".index").children().first();
                    hiddenInput.val(index);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"3cb43da0b95a4e85b5516b7a9fd604d5"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:63777/83db435e9ea240748a606c667677694e/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out this DotNetFiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/UjxtUW - given to me by the master Stephen Muecke. Might point you in the right direction, as you will need to set the names of your objects correctly in JS, for the ModelBinder to pick them up and create your `IList<Model>`. HTH

Comment: I think you should being using @Html.TextboxFor for in order for the model to bind correctly. If you need to use displayfor I think you need to create a hidden value along with it.

Comment: @GeoffJames Not sure if that is the same or not, as in that case, the list is part of the model, and the model itself is being passed to the controller. In this case, I'm passing a list of the model directly to the controller.

Comment: The fiddle I mentioned is what worked for me when I had the same problem. In your view, I would suggest writing out an input for the Index, rather than using the `@Html` helper (it can also prove a bit long winded). e.g. within your foreach: `<input type="text" name="sliders[i].Index" value="@Model[i].Index" ... />`, as Ian has already alluded to below

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris Use my solution, I verified that it works. The problem was the name of your button which was 'slides', same as the name of the parameter on Post Action. Changing the name of button to something else would solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model on `HttpPost` will be populated using values submitted in the form.
In your case, you do not seem to be generating any input fields to identify the rows.

What you should be having is one hidden field for `Id` and one hidden field for `Index` in each row.

`DisplayFor` only generated the labels for you and the labels won't be submitted with form. Alongwith each Label(`DisplayFor`), generate a Hidden field too (`HiddenFor`), for at least Id and Index if not for all other fields.

Other than this, **the issue is with the name of your submit button which is set to 'slides'**. This is also the name of the parameter on your `POST` action. Either change the name of button or change the name of `IList` parameter on your `Action`

This is what your view should look like:

```
@model IList<WebApplication2.Models.Slide>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Reorder</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table grid" id="sort">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Index)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Section)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().Content)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().ImageData)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().ImageDescription)
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                </td>
                <td class="index">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Index, new
                    {
                        htmlAttributes = new
                        {
                            @readonly = "true"
                        }
                    })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Section)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Content)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new
                              {
                                  id = Model[i].Id
                              })" alt="@Model[i].ImageDescription"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].ImageDescription)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-default" name="noslides"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#sort tbody').sortable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $("#sort tbody tr").each(function(index, element) {
                    var hiddenInput = $(element).children(".index").children().first();
                hiddenInput.val(index);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK, using the `@Html.EditorFor()` will only output `"[0].Index"` and so on, in the HTML. It would be necessary in the OP's instance to prefix it with `"slides"`, by declaring the HTML by hand in the view - e.g.: `"slides[" + i + "].Index"` -> `"slides[0].Index"` in order for the ModelBinder to pick this up in the controller.

Comment: @GeoffJames ModelBinder picks `[0].Index`, `slides` prefix is redundant. The issue was the name of his button (same as the parameter on Post Action).

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that the name of the button was supposed to be the name of the parameter to the action. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: No, that would mean that ModelBinder would try to set the value of parameter to string 'Save Order' which is the value of button field.

Comment: @sachin very good eyes you have indeed (I didn't notice that)... +1d for you

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `List` is that the `name` attribute produced in the `View` for all the `input` elements do not contain required prefix.

In your case, when you generate the `List` of inputs in the `View` by using `HTML helper`, the name generated does not contain `slides[i]` prefix. You could check it with your `HTML` debugger.

```
//to be readable by the controller, it should be like this:
<input type="text" name="slides[0].TypeName" ...>

//but by using HTML helper Html.EditorFor, the following is generated
<input type="text" name="TypeName" ...>
```

Thus, instead of having all your inputs into place (having `slides[i]` prefix). You have multiple items with the same name!

My suggestion is for you to add HTMLAttribute name in the HTML creation and assign your name with the prefix `slides[i]`, something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Index, new
                {
                    htmlAttributes = new
                    {                            
                        name = "slides[" + i + "].Index"
                    }
                })
```

For `Index` property. You may do the same for the rests.

Else, you could also generate the HTML *without* using `HTML helper`. Take your `Index` as an example, this is how it would look like (taken and edited from the HTML generated you posted):

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
       data-val-number="The field Index must be a number." 
       data-val-required="The Index field is required." 
       name="slides[" + @i + "].Index" 
       readonly="True" type="number" 
       value="@Model[i].Index" />
```

Comment: I believe that the prefix is generated when using `Model[Index]` syntax, prefix would not have been generated if a `foreach` loop would have been used instead.

Comment: So the items do have a `[i]` prefix, just not the `slidesl[i]`. I'll try adding the `slides` portion.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris Inspect the HTML that is being generated.

Comment: @Ian With the edit you suggested, the same HTML is being generated as before: `name="[i].Index"` where `i` is the appropriate value. So, for some reason, the `name` attribute is not being changed properly.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris in that case, then you probably need to consider the option by *not* using the HTML helper... I did it this way when I encountered the same issue: I copied the HTML generated and then put it in my `View` file and generate the html with the correct prefix myself.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris I just verified that [i].Index does work, there is some other problem with your code. The only input field being generated right now is the Index, right?

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris if you could add the HTML generated in your post, then I can easily give accurate example in my answer post... Otherwise, it should look like... `<input type="text" name="slides[" + @i.ToString() + "].Index" ..>`

Comment: @Ian - just to save a few characters, you don't need to worry about `i.ToString()`, just `i` will work fine on its own :) FWIW, I've experienced similar issues to this in the past, and what I suggested in the OP comments and what you have put in your answer ring true, so I've +1'd you

Comment: @GeoffJames opps, you are right. :P old habit dies slowly... "your answer ring true, so I've +1'd you" thanks!

Comment: @Ian Generated HTML has been added.

Comment: @sachin As suggested by others, I added every field via `Html.HiddenFor()`.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris example added

Comment: @Ian The issue actually was the name of his button conflicting with the name of IList parameter, rest of the things in his code were fine (except missing a necessary hidden Id field to identify records).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=> x.FieldName)
@Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.FieldName)
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.FieldName)
```

As mentioned, DisplayFor does not bind to the model.